# Katakana Surnames

Tags: katakana, names, law

When my son was born, katakana surnames were not permitted.
At some point, this law seems to have been changed, and children born now may be registered with a katakana "western" surname.
When did this change happen?

Comment: What was the alternative to registering a katakana surname if that's all the parents had?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe since 1985.

From [here](https://www.dailyshincho.jp/article/2019/10190558/?all=1&page=2)

> ところが、この「日本的氏名を用いる」という規定は1980年の国籍法、戸籍法の改正に伴って削除された。読売新聞が87年6月に報じた「韓国姓への復姓認める　帰化二世が申し立て／京都家裁」という記事に、以下のような記述がある。

> > 《六十年一月の国籍法、戸籍法改正で、法務省は「帰化許可申請の手引」にある「日本的氏名を用いる」という規定を削除、漢字かカナなら外国姓のままで、帰化が可能になった》

> この改正によって、基本的には、ラモス瑠偉やリーチマイケルという名前が認められたことになる。さらに結婚が影響を与えるケースもある。

I'm not sure why the above says 1980, but 六十年 means 昭和60年＝1985, which looks like when the law was changed (by googling).

Comment: 1980年 could be a typo for 1980年代.